# Can access share from one machine but not other?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

From machine A, I can access a server and its shares.

[image]

From machine B, I cannot access it.

[image]

Notes:

- I can ping 10.88.5.80 from both machines.
- Both machines are on the same domain.
- I am using the same domain account from both machines when I try to access the server.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Make sure both machines are on the same version of OS. Make sure Network Discovery, F&P Sharing and Password protected sharing are all ON.  Restart both computers. Also talk to the Domain Admin.

Comment: If it's an older server you're accessing, you may need to enable SMB1.0 File Sharing Support on machine B.

Comment: @John All those settings are already on. I am the domain admin.

Comment: @n8te Yes!! That was it. It is working now.

Comment: You should be really careful at this late date enabling SMBv1.

Comment: @John What is the risk? Is there an alternative?

Comment: The risk is now very high as SMBv1 is unsafe. The only alternative is to turn SMBv1 OFF and just use a higher version of SMB.

Comment: @john Maybe its worth providing a meaningful comment as to what makes v1 insecure (Im not very knowledgable here  i assume protocol weaknesses so wannacry hacking type risks?).  Would it be worth looking at to what is required to exploit this - ie if its a home lan, how much protection does NAT provide to external attackers?

Comment: Here is a very reasonable source of the SMBv1 risks: .......    https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858    I hope this helps.  There was a transition to SMBv2+ some years back but SMBv1 is truly a big risk now